# How to create a method to accept and return any type of ObjectProperty<?>?

Tags: java, generics, javafx, enums

My application has an object containing multiple `ObjectProperty<Enum>` fields. I am trying to write a helper method that does the following:

- Accept any type of `ObjectProperty<Enum>` as a parameter
- Display a `ChoiceDialog` popup, allowing the user to select a different text value for the `enum`
- Update the value of the `enum` in the passed `ObjectProperty` itself

I am not very familiar with generics at all, but I believe the following might work (no compiler errors):

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt,
                                                           ObjectProperty<Class<E>> property,
                                                           Window owner) {

    // Create the dialog to ask for a new enum value
    ChoiceDialog<E> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Value");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);
    dialog.setContentText(prompt);
    dialog.initOwner(owner);

    // Currently, this displays the enum NAME in the ComboBox, rather than it's text value        
    dialog.getItems().setAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(property.get().getEnumConstants()));

    Stage dialogStage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    dialogStage.getIcons().add(ImageHelper.appIcon());

    Optional<E> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        Utility.printTempMsg(result.toString());
        Utility.printTempMsg(Enum.valueOf(property.get(), result.toString()).toString());
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, I am not sure how to pass the `ObjectProperty` to this method. When trying to pass my property through as follows, I'm getting a compiler error:

```
linkEditRequestSource.setOnAction(event ->
            editEnumProperty(
                    "Select new Request Source:",
                    simpleObject.requestSourceProperty(),       // <-- no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that RequestSource conforms to Class<E>
                    lblRequestSource.getScene().getWindow()
            )
    );
```

I also do not know how to then set the value of the `ObjectProperty` after the user has selected one.

Below is a non-working MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceDialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.util.Optional;

enum RequestSource {
    ACQUIRED("Acquisition"),
    MANUAL("Manually Entered"),
    MANAGER("Manager Reported");

    private final String text;

    RequestSource(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

public class GenericEnumProperty extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt,
                                                               ObjectProperty<Class<E>> property,
                                                               Window owner) {

        // Create the dialog to ask for a new enum value
        ChoiceDialog<E> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Edit Value");
        dialog.setHeaderText(null);
        dialog.setContentText(prompt);
        dialog.initOwner(owner);

        dialog.getItems().setAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(property.get().getEnumConstants()));

        Optional<E> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            // This should actually set the value of the underlying object's ObjectProperty<RequestSource> to
            // the new value selected in the ComboBox
            System.out.println(Enum.valueOf(property.get(), result.toString()).toString());

            // Will use this value to track which properties have been modified
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Label to display current value of RequestSource
        Label lblRequestSource = new Label();

        // Create a new object
        SimpleObject simpleObject = new SimpleObject(RequestSource.ACQUIRED);

        // Bind the property value to the label
        lblRequestSource.textProperty().bind(simpleObject.requestSourceProperty().asString());

        // Hyperlink to open value editor
        Hyperlink linkEditRequestSource = new Hyperlink("Request Source:");
        linkEditRequestSource.setOnAction(event ->
                editEnumProperty(
                        "Select new Request Source:",
                        simpleObject.requestSourceProperty(),       // <-- no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that RequestSource conforms to Class<E>
                        lblRequestSource.getScene().getWindow()
                )
        );

        root.getChildren().add(
                new HBox(5, linkEditRequestSource, lblRequestSource)
        );

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class SimpleObject {

    private final ObjectProperty<RequestSource> requestSourceProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public SimpleObject(RequestSource source) {
        this.requestSourceProperty.set(source);
    }

    public RequestSource getRequestSourceProperty() {
        return requestSourceProperty.get();
    }

    public void setRequestSourceProperty(RequestSource requestSourceProperty) {
        this.requestSourceProperty.set(requestSourceProperty);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<RequestSource> requestSourceProperty() {
        return requestSourceProperty;
    }
}
```

---

So really there are a few related questions here:

- How can I pass a generic `ObjectProperty<Enum>` to the method?
- Is it possible to display the enum's text values instead of the enum name?
- How do I set the value of the `Property` after the user has selected a new one?

Comment: Why do you have `ObjectProperty<Class<E>>` instead of `ObjectProperty<E>`?

Comment: I am not sure, @James_D. I thought that was necessary to ensure it would accept an enum of any type. Will try `ObjectProperty<E>` instead, though that does not provide the `getEnumConstants()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you need to pass to the generic method should be an `ObjectProperty<E>`, not an `ObjectProperty<Class<E>>`. Then you can do:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt,
                                                           ObjectProperty<E> property,
                                                           Window owner) {

    // Create the dialog to ask for a new enum value
    ChoiceDialog<E> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Value");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);
    dialog.setContentText(prompt);
    dialog.initOwner(owner);

    
    
    dialog.getItems().setAll(property.get().getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants());

    Optional<E> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    boolean changed = result.isPresent();
    result.ifPresent(property::set);
    return changed ;
}
```

Now your example code works as-is.

There is one caveat here: if `property.get()` returns `null`, then this will throw a null pointer exception at

```
dialog.getItems().setAll(property.get().getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants());
```

If you want to support "unset" properties whose value is null, I think you need an extra parameter in the method, to represent the type:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt,
                                                           Class<E> enumType,
                                                           ObjectProperty<E> property,
                                                           Window owner) {

    // Create the dialog to ask for a new enum value
    ChoiceDialog<E> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Value");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);
    dialog.setContentText(prompt);
    dialog.initOwner(owner);

    
    
    dialog.getItems().setAll(enumType.getEnumConstants());

    Optional<E> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    boolean changed = result.isPresent();
    result.ifPresent(property::set);
    return changed ;
}
```

In this case, you just need this slight modification:

```
    linkEditRequestSource.setOnAction(event ->
            editEnumProperty(
                    "Select new Request Source:",
                    RequestSource.class,
                    simpleObject.requestSourceProperty(),      
                    lblRequestSource.getScene().getWindow()
            )
    );
```

Your one remaining question is

> Is it possible to display the enum's text values instead of the enum name?

Since not all enums have a `getText()` method, there's no particularly easy way to hook into the `getText()` method you've defined to display the enum values. Generally, you could offer an optional `Function<E, String>` parameter via overloading:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(
    String prompt,
    ObjectProperty<E> property,
    Window owner) {

    return editEnumProperty(prompt, property, Object::toString, owner);
}

public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(
    String prompt,
    ObjectProperty<E> property,
    Function<? super E, String> displayText,
    Window owner) {

    // now what...?
}
```

but since there's also no access (as far as I can tell) to the choice box (or combo box?) displayed by the `ChoiceDialog`, there's no obvious way to configure how the text is displayed.

You could at this point roll your own version of the `ChoiceDialog` (gaining access to the popup control); for example:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt, ObjectProperty<E> property,
        Function<? super E, String> displayText, Window owner) {

    Dialog<E> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    ChoiceBox<E> choice = new ChoiceBox<>();
    choice.setConverter(new StringConverter<E>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(E object) {
            return displayText.apply(object);
        }

        @Override
        public E fromString(String string) {
            // Not actually needed...
            return null;
        }
        
    });
    choice.getItems().setAll(property.get().getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants());
    choice.getSelectionModel().select(property.get());
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(new HBox(5, new Label(prompt), choice));
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.CANCEL, ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.setResultConverter(button -> 
        button == ButtonType.OK ? choice.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() : null
    );
    return dialog.showAndWait().map(value -> {
        property.set(value);
        return true ;
    }).orElse(false);
    
}
```

or you could try an ugly hack such as this, which stores the string values and corresponding eval values in a `Map`:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean editEnumProperty(String prompt, ObjectProperty<E> property,
        Function<? super E, String> displayText, Window owner) {

// Create the dialog to ask for a new enum value
    ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Value");
    dialog.setHeaderText(null);
    dialog.setContentText(prompt);
    dialog.initOwner(owner);
    
    Map<String, E> displayValueLookup = Stream.of(property.get().getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(displayText, Function.identity()));

    dialog.getItems().setAll(displayValueLookup.keySet());

    return  dialog.showAndWait()
            .map(displayValueLookup::get)
            .map(value -> {
                property.set(value);
                return true ;
            })
            .orElse(false);
}
```

and now of course

```
    linkEditRequestSource.setOnAction(event -> editEnumProperty(
        "Select new Request Source:",
        simpleObject.requestSourceProperty(), 
        RequestSource::getText,
        lblRequestSource.getScene().getWindow()));
```

Comment: Thank you, James. This works perfectly and I understand much more now. And, I agree this might be a good case for overriding the `toString()` method, though I'm always hesitant to do so.

Comment: @Zephyr Yes: I agree with that hesitation. It's not actually that difficult to roll your own "choice dialog" using the existing `Dialog` class; I think that's the way to go. See edit.